# DSE 4.7 and spark-sql driver

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use these links in order to make spark-sql and tableau work:

- http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2014/10/tableau-spark-sql-big-data-just-got-even-more-supercharged-33799
- https://www.concur.com/blog/en-us/connect-tableau-to-sparksql
  to run spark-sql on top of DSE-analytics from Tableau.

**What I did:**

- enabled spark on DSE side
- started `sudo dse start-spark-sql-thriftserver`
- I see that 10000 port is LISTEN by start-spark-sql-thriftserver

> vagrant@dsenode01:~$ sudo netstat -alnpt | grep 10000 tcp        0
>   0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   5908/java
>
> vagrant@dsenode01:~$ sudo ps -ef | grep 5908 root      5908     1  3
>   09:26 pts/0    00:00:31 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre//bin/java -cp
>   :/etc/dse/spark: ....

When I try to test ODBC connection, I get an error
[image: ODBC driver failure]

Also I see weird thrift exception in **spark-sql-thriftserver** log.
What it could be?

```
dse.system_memory_in_mb=3009 -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader -Dspark.cassandra.connection.host=192.168.56.10 -Dlogback.configurationFile=/etc/dse/spark/logback-spark.xml -Xms512M -Xmx512M org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 --master spark://192.168.56.30:7077 spark-internal --hiveconf disableVirtualColumns=true
========================================

ERROR 2015-06-15 09:29:56 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:208) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
ERROR 2015-06-15 09:36:03 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:208) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
ERROR 2015-06-15 09:51:04 org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:208) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216) ~[hive-exec-0.12.0.7.jar:0.12.0.7]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is good conf example:

- use Simba Spark ODBC driver v 1.00.08.1008 (maybe it could change later...)
- create system DSN
- **NB**: we didn't use any auth mechanism. Select auth mechanism "User name" and **DO NOT** input user name, leave it blank.

It works, thanks, god. Please see the screenshot
[image: How the driver looks like]